# How to add double quotes to the output values in a Resultset when the column datatype is String?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to run the below query and insert the output of it into another table (postgres db):

```
    String ssnQuery = "SELECT period_year, period_name, period_num, NULL as count_of_issues,
    ledger_id,
    balancing_segment,
    Count(*) AS count_of_account_segments,
    Sum(accounted_period_net_dr) AS balance_accounted_period_net_dr,
    Sum(accounted_period_net_cr) AS balance_accounted_period_net_cr,
    Round(Sum(accounted_period_net_dr_cr)) AS balance_accounted_period_net_dr_cr_diff,
    Sum(entered_period_net_dr) AS balance_entered_period_net_dr,
    Sum(entered_period_net_cr) AS balance_entered_period_net_cr,
    Round(Sum(entered_period_net_dr_cr)) AS balance_entered_period_net_dr_cr_diff,
    Sum(begin_balance_dr) AS begin_balance_dr,
    Sum(begin_balance_cr) AS begin_balance_cr,
    Round(Sum(net_beginning_balance)) AS net_beginning_balance,
    Round(Sum(net_closing_balance)) AS net_closing_balance
    FROM schema.tablename";

try {
    pstmnt       = financeConnection.prepareStatement(ssnQuery);
    rs           = pstmnt.executeQuery();
    rsmd         = rs.getMetaData();
    for(int i=1; i<=rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
        if(i == 1) {
            queryColumns = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        } else if(i<7) {
            queryColumns += ", " + rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        } else {
            queryColumns += ", value_" + (i-7);
        }
    }
    while (rs.next()) {
        queryValues = " ";
        for(String colname: columnNames) {
            if(queryValues.isEmpty()) {
                queryValues = rs.getString(colname);
            } else {
                queryValues += rs.getString(colname) + ", ";
            }
        }
        remCommas = queryValues.replaceAll(", $", "");
        insertQuery = "INSERT INTO bdmerge.gen_audit_func_hive_results (run_id, run_date, run_date_ist" + queryColumns + ") VALUES (" + runid +"," + utcTimeStamp + "," + istTimeStamp + "," + remCommas + ")";
        System.out.println("Final Insert query: " + insertQuery);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To insert the output of above query, I formed the insert query according the column names in the destination table as below:

```
INSERT INTO schema.destinationTable (run_id, run_date, run_date_ist, source_system_type, source_system, module, source_table_name, period_year, period_name, period_num, count_of_issues, count_of_accounted_issues, count_of_entered_issues, value_0, value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5, value_6, value_7, value_8, value_9, value_10, value_11, value_12) VALUES (781,2018-11-12 08:15:32.0,2018-11-12 13:45:32.0, 2018, OCT-18, 10, null, 1, 1, 2073, ATRS, 6135, 6.2778220466107E11, 6.277946274560101E11, -1.2422795E7, 5.929031383587201E11, 5.9291556115366E11, -1.2422795E7, 3.931397937759116E13, 3.9313979377591164E13, 0.0)
```

But the destination table's columns:

```
run_id, count_of_issues, count_of_accounted_issues, count_of_entered_issues
```

are in numeric format (working on postgres db) and all others are varchar(1000).

In order to insert the varchar data, I need to enclose the column values from **value_0** till **value_12** in double quotes.

Without properly modifying the data, I am getting SQLException while inserting which is expected.

Is there any way I can just enclose those varchar column values from the resultSet in double quotes and insert them into destination table?

Comment: Is string escaping "\"" not working? i dont get it. I rather would use a PreparedStatement because there is no escaping necessary and no possible risk of sql injection

Comment: You could almost certainly combine the SELECT and the INSERT into a single statement and not have to worry about any of this, and in any case you should certainly be using a prepared statement rather than concatenating strings into an SQL statement, which woiuld also eliminate this problem completely.

Comment: I need to change the column names of the query to the ones in destination table where I have name them "value_0, value_1,..." based on the number of columns after column index 6. It is hard to explain & I did that part in the code. But I couldn't come up with the logic to enclose the column values in quotes as I mentioned in question.

Comment: There is nothing there that mitigates against either of the suggestions I made.

Comment: Well ok. Let me try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes to the string values; Use Escape characters, like this:

```
String quotedStr = "Non Quoted," + " \"Quoted\".";
```

Modifying your code to address the problem:

```
   while (rs.next()) {
        queryValues = " ";
        int i = 0; 
        for(String colname: columnNames) {

            if(queryValues.isEmpty()) {
                queryValues = rs.getString(colname);
            } else {
            if (i >= 7)
                    queryValues += "\"" + rs.getString(colname) +"\"" + ", ";
            }
            else
                queryValues += rs.getString(colname) + ", ";
            i++;
        }
```